# How to close specific rule in sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

[image]

I want to disable this rule for the sonar cloud, where can I configure it?
I have looked up the sonarqube doc. Unfortunately, I didn't find the rule.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/tag/react
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As someone answered early,  add these 2 lines to `sonar-project.properties` will close this rule globally.

```
sonar.javascript.jsx.lint.props-should-not-use-functions.severity=none
sonar.javascript.jsx.lint.props-should-not-use-arrow-functions.severity=none
```